# Vagrant vs simple copying of VM files

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I wonder if there any necessity in Vagrant when there is an ability to just copy the VM files and open them on another host machine?

Going this way we are getting things done even more quickly than Vagrant's setup of the guest and spending less traffic same time. Doesn't we?
The only restraint this way is the necessity of storing a clean VM image with pure set up development environment, I guess.

Comment: it must be someone overwhelmingly wise downvoted my post and left it uncommented with no pointing out what's wrong with the question or where am I wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing already constructed VMs across different hosts can be a bad idea for many reasons, several of which are listed here:

- Image files can be *big*, hindering transfer between different machines and across network.
- Your image file can be "tainted" by unwanted software, possibly used for debugging and/or other uses. It can *(and will)* confuse other developers, making it harder for them to reproduce different effects and test their own code.
- Image size also makes it impossible to share it using VCS (e.g. handling binary files in git is unwieldy and often requires use of external tools and extensions).

Using Vagrant, you are side-stepping many of these issues by sharing only a "declarative" description of your desired environment. Compared to sharing  full VM image file, Vagrant config file has following advantages:

- Being a simple text file with DSL, it is very small and can be shared using VCS without any trouble.
- It can provide clear and concise description of desired system environment, while inspecting a fully constructed VM can be tiresome and time-consuming.
- Vagrant provides powerful features for setting up your system, e.g. creating shared folders, configuring virtual network interfaces and so on.

In my experience, having a way to recreate your development environment from a clean slate proved a huge time-saver and decreased complexity of testing software under development.